# NumPy Boolean Array in Index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say we have two arrays

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(2,2)
b = np.array([True, False, False, True]).reshape(2,2)
```

gives

```
a = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]] 
b = [[True, False],
     [False, True]]
```

We can do a[b] to get only the values of b that are true giving us
`[1, 4]`

I tried to do a[not b] to get those that are false but got an error. I know I can do `a[b == False]` but want to do it in a Pythonic way.

Any solution?

Comment: `a[~b]` might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`np.logical_not`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html) or the [`~` operator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html):

```py
>>> a[np.logical_not(b)]
>>> a[~b]
```